# Time reversal in Region III in the Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, wormholes

Here is a standard Kruskal-Szekeres diagram:

[[image]]
The region III coordinate time $t$ is constant on lines through the origin going from $t = +\infty$ where regions III and IV intersect backwards to $t = -\infty$ where regions III and II intersect.

As Kruskal time T increases in region III, the region III coordinate time t therefore decreases from $+ \infty$ (where regions III and IV intersect in a line) to $- \infty$ (where regions III and II intersect in a line).

Now if a particle is in region III, then we know that the particle moves UP (in the direction of positive Kruskal time T, in an angle $\leq 45^\circ$ from vertical), which implies the particle will move in the direction of negative region III coordinate time. Thus, it seems like an observer in region III experiences time running backwards. I must be making a mistake here, because time running backwards seems counterintuitive. Is this correct, that time is running backwards in region III, or how do I make sense of the diagram?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/500520/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximally extended Schwarzschild spacetime is time-orientable. There are two possible choices for the time orientation. On this diagram, the standard orientation is one in which time runs upward throughout the entire diagram. There is not a reversal of orientation for I relative to III. The mapping to Schwarzschild coordinate charts doesn't impose an orientation. The future does not have to be the direction of increasing Schwarzschild t.