# How to relate the Schwarzschild time $t$ to the status of the wormhole featured in the Kruskal diagram?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, wormholes

The maximally extended Schwarzschild spacetime as described by a Kruskal diagram features a wormhole which is dynamical. As Kruskal time $T$ elapses, a spacelike hypersurface hits the past singularity, then the wormhole opens up and the hypersurface extends to the parallel universe, eventually the wormhole pinches off and the hypersurface hits the future singularity.

However, it is not clear to me how the Schwarzschild time $t$ relates to the status of the wormhole.

My question is:

If we consider for instance the black hole in the center of our galaxy and our “now” as observers, which is the status of the (hypothetical) wormhole? Is it still to open up, or is it open “now”, or has it already pinched off?

Comment: duplicate or near-duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/500520/is-the-schwarzschild-wormhole-einstein-rosen-bridge-time-dependent

Answer (score 1):

In the Kruskal diagram, this "wormhole" consists of a single point in the diagram (i.e. a sphere in the spacetime). Hence it exists for only a single moment in Kruskal time. In the Krusal diagram, lines of constant Scharzschild time $t$ are straight lines passing through this point. So the "wormhole" exists for all values of the Schwarzschild time.

Note that in general relativity there is no well defined notion of "now" for a single observer; any spacelike surface between the past and future lightcones can be considered "now" for that observer. In particular, there is nothing special about Schwarzschild time (in this respect).

Note 2: The hypothetical "wormhole" exists only for eternal black holes (i.e. ones that have also have a past horizon). Dynamically formed black holes (like presumably the one in the center of our galaxy) will not have a "wormhole".

Comment: Do you mean that to my question there is no answer?

Comment: *So the "wormhole" exists for [all???] values of the Schwarzschild time* One could argue that this is only true for an eternal Schwarzschild black hole of constant mass. If the BH is growing (as it must for realistic model) the $SO(1,1)$ symmetry of the Kruskal metric is broken and different Schwarzschild times are no longer equivalent.

Comment: @A.V.S. It only makes sense to talk a wormhole for an eternal black hole to begin with, since it exists on the bifurcation surface of the past and future horizons. So for a dynamically formed black hole there is no wormhole at all.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was leading to. Your answer (its first version) made statements about model incompatible with the question (*the black hole in the center of our galaxy*) without mentioning it.

Comment: So, the conclusion is that an eternal black hole is simply a mathematical "curiosity", but not a realistic model?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is *the* conclusion, but it is pretty accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.